# Vuejs table with dynamic columns connectted to flask API

Tags: rest, vue.js, flask, flask-restful

I am building a web application using Flask, SQLAlchemy and Vuejs. I have built an API to pass data from my database to be displayed in a table, built as a Vuejs component. I want my table component to be as generic as possible so I reuse it in different places.
For my first attempt, my API returns data as follows:

```
data = [
{
firstName: ‘Joe’,
    lastName: ‘Bradley’,
    email: ‘joe@company.com
},
{
firstName: ‘Mary’,
    lastName: ‘Kelly’,
    email: ‘mary@company.com
},
{etc....}
]
```

Right now my Vue table component has column headings hard coded in but, I want the table component to be able to dynamically change the number of columns based on what data it receives. I don’t want the headings to be hard coded. I might have a different table that displays 4 totally different columns of data. How should I set the column headings in the Vue component?

Some ideas I had:

- Include a list of columns headings in the API response so that the
  table know what headings to use?
- Make a separate API end point that returns a mapping of column
  headings to database field names.
- Just hard code the headings into the Vue table and define a new table
  component for each time I want to display a different data set.

Can anybody offer any best practise advice for a situation like this? I’m self taught and pretty new to this as you have probably gathered from the question. Thanks in advance!